# detecting image size programmatically -iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

My application lets user take a picture with default camera on iPhone and send it to a server. Before sending it I would like to check the image size and let's say if the size is larger than 500 KB I would let the user know filesize is too big and would not send it. Is there a way to check the image size programmatically?
Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you convert it to `NSData`, you can check the `length` property. The file size in MB is bytes divide by 2^20.

To convert to NSData use `UIImagePNGRepresentation()`

```
UIImage *myImage = ...
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage);
```